# One ActionListener for two classes

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes with JPanels which contain JTextField and JButton in one. I want to write something in one JTextField and by pressing JButton print it in anothers JPanels JTextField.

I did my best and created this code and it doesn't show me any errors, but it's not doing what I want. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

```java
public class RevenuesPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        public JTextField tfRevenues;
        public static String sRevenues;
        public JLabel lRevenues;
        public JButton save;

        public RevenuesPanel(){
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Revenues"));
        FlowLayout manager = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(manager);
        JLabel lRevenues = new JLabel("Revenues:");
        add(lRevenues);
        this.tfRevenues= new JTextField(10);
        add(this.tfRevenues);
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ResultPanel());
        this.add(save);
        setVisible(true);
        }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      sRevenues=tfRevenues.getText();
    }
      public static String getRevenues() {
      return sRevenues;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ResultPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public JTextField field;
    public String result;

    public ResultPanel() {
        FlowLayout manager = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(manager);
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Results"));
        field = new JTextField(10);
        add(field);
        setVisible(false);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    result = RevenuesPanel.getRevenues();
    field.setText(String.valueOf(result));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
save.addActionListener(new ResultPanel());
```

Yes, you are adding a ResultPanel listener to the save button, and yes (contrary to the what the other answer states) it *is* being called, but it is the ***wrong*** ResultPanel -- it's a ***new*** one, and not the one being displayed.

One way for this to succeed is for you to add the actual ResultsPanel that is being displayed as the button's Action listener, to not create ***two*** different ResultsPanel, one displayed and one used as a listener. How this is done will depend on where you create the actual displayed ResultsPanel.

I would give your `RevenuesPanel` a public method, something like,

```
public void addSaveListener(ActionListener listener) {
    save.addActioniListener(listener);
}
```

and then pass the *displayed* ResultsPanel into the *displayed* RevenuesPanel by calling this method.

Also, this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    result = RevenuesPanel.getRevenues();
    field.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Looks to be an issue since you appear to be trying to call a *static* method off of the RevenuesPanel class with `RevenuesPanel.getRevenues();`

Again, for this to work, you would need to have an actual instance of the *displayed* `RevenuesPanel`, and call an instance method on that instance.

Also, this:

```
public static String sRevenues;
```

is wrong. You should not be using static anything here other than the main method.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TwoPanels {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final RevenuesPanel revenuesPanel = new RevenuesPanel();
        final ResultPanel resultPanel = new ResultPanel();
        
        revenuesPanel.addSaveListener(e -> {
            String revenues = revenuesPanel.getRevenues();
            resultPanel.setRevenues(revenues);
        });
        
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        mainPanel.add(revenuesPanel);
        mainPanel.add(resultPanel);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class RevenuesPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField tfRevenues = new JTextField(5);
    private JButton save = new JButton("Save");

    public RevenuesPanel(){
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Revenues"));
        add(tfRevenues);
        add(save);
    }

    public String getRevenues() {
        return tfRevenues.getText();
    }
    
    public void addSaveListener(ActionListener listener) {
        save.addActionListener(listener);
        tfRevenues.addActionListener(listener);
    }

}
```

```
class ResultPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(5);

    public ResultPanel() {
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Results"));
        add(new JLabel("Results:"));
        add(resultField);
        resultField.setFocusable(false);
    }
    
    public void setRevenues(String revenues) {
        resultField.setText(revenues);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for asking obvious questions. Is addSaveListener have to be in main? I have class MainFrame where i connect all panels and separate class main

Answer (score -1):

Your actionListener in RevenuesPanel is not being called. Try creating a method in ResultPanel such as:

```
public static void addTextToTextField() {

result = RevenuesPanel.getRevenues();

// You don't need String.valueOf() because result is a String.
field.setText(result);

}
```

Then later calling on the first actionListener from RevenuesPanel, adding RevenuesPanel ActionListener on the "save" JButton.